# Two way or send/reply SMS application using Tropo Web API

Tags: javascript, sms, tropo

Hi I am new to [Tropo](https://tropo.com),

I am able to send SMS to the mobile number using Tropo WebApi call() method.

Now I want to enable two way SMS communication with my WEB Application. Want to capture reply from the user mobile to my application?

Below is the scenario:

**MyApplication <--*sms/reply*---> TropoAllication <--*sms/reply*--> User Mobile**

Is there any way to get SMS reply back to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try Timeless SMS – Using CouchDB to Track Two Way SMS Conversations at https://www.tropo.com/2012/03/couchdb-sms/